# Mybatis Spring annotation exception

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

Hi i have problem with autowire annotation using spring and mybatis. What i am doing wrong - in tutorials we should only autowire interface mapped by xml file and scan folder in servlet configuration.

Tomcat return NoSuchBeanDefintionException like dont see the UserMapper Interface. Create bean in se4vlet config return error it cant create bean from interface.

Thanks for help.

```
    <annotation-driven />
    <!-- enable autowire -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.xxx.eppm.controllers">        /context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.xxx.mappers"></context:component-scan>

    <resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/frontend/css/" />
    <resources mapping="/js/**" location="/WEB-INF/frontend/js/" /> 


    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
         <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eppm"/>
         <beans:property name="username" value="root"/>
         <beans:property name="password" value=""/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/frontend/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".htm"   />
        <beans:property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />        
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <beans:property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="pl.xxx.mappers"/>
        <beans:property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:/resources/mappers/*.xml" />       
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="basePackage" value="pl.xxx.mybatis.mappers" />
    </beans:bean>
```

userMapper.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC '-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN'
  'http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd'>
     <mapper namespace='pl.xxx.mappers.UserMapper'>

    <select id="getUserById" parameterType="int" resultType="pl.xxx.users.User">
        SELECT  id,
                username,
                password,
                isActive
        FROM USERS
        WHERE id = #{userId}
    </select>

    <select id="getUserByName" parameterType="string" resultType="pl.xxx.users.User">
        SELECT  id,
                username,
                password,
                isActive
        FROM USERS
        WHERE username = #{username}
    </select>   

    <resultMap type="User" id="UserResult">
        <id property="id" column="id" />
        <result property="username" column="username" />
        <result property="password" column="password" />        
        <result property="isActive" column="isActive" />
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getAllUsers" resultMap="UserResult">
        SELECT * FROM USERS
    </select>

    <insert id="insertUser" parameterType="User" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id">
        INSERT INTO 
            USERS(username, password, isActive) 
            VALUES(#{username}, #{password}, #{isActive})
    </insert>

    <update id="updateUser" parameterType="User">
        UPDATE 
            USERS
        SET
            username = #{username},
            password = #{password},
            isActive = #{isActive}
        WHERE 
            id = #{id}
    </update> 

    <delete id="deleteUser" parameterType="int">
        DELETE FROM 
            USERS
        WHERE
            id = #{id} 
    </delete>

</mapper>
```

UserService.java

```
    @Service
    public class UserDAO implements UserMapper {

    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    public void insertUser(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public User getUserById(Integer userId) {
        return userMapper.getUserById(userId);
    }

    public User getUserByName(String username) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void updateUser(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void deleteUser(Integer userId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

UserMapper.java

```
     package pl.xxx.mappers;

     import java.util.List;

     import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

     import pl.xxx.users.User; 


    public interface UserMapper {
     public void insertUser(User user);

     public User getUserById(Integer userId);

     public User getUserByName(String username);

     public List<User> getAllUsers();

     public void updateUser(User user);

     public void deleteUser(Integer userId);
     }
```

Controller

```
    @Controller
    public class MainPageController {

    private UserMapper UserDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String mainController(){
        System.out.println(UserDao.getUserById(1));
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/test")
    public String testController(){
        return "index";
    }
    }
```

Trace:

```
    HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet SpringDispatcherServlet threw exception

    type Exception report

    message Servlet.init() for servlet SpringDispatcherServlet threw exception

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet SpringDispatcherServlet threw exception
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    root cause

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private pl.xxx.mappers.UserMapper pl.xxx.mappers.UserDAO.userMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [pl.xxx.mappers.UserMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    root cause

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private pl.xxx.mappers.UserMapper pl.xxx.mappers.UserDAO.userMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [pl.xxx.mappers.UserMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    root cause

    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [pl.xxx.mappers.UserMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.

    Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

I have one more problem:

```
         org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    pl.xxx.eppm.controllers.MainPageController.mainController(MainPageController.java:22)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.
```

And last error then

```
        org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): pl.xxx.mappers.UserMapper.getUserById
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    root cause

    org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): pl.xxx.mappers.UserMapper.getUserById
        org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MapperMethod.java:189)
        org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:43)
        org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedMapperMethod(MapperProxy.java:58)
        org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:51)
        com.sun.proxy.$Proxy132.getUserById(Unknown Source)
        pl.xxx.mappers.UserDAO.getUserById(UserDAO.java:22)
        pl.xxx.eppm.controllers.MainPageController.mainController(MainPageController.java:24)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.

    Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

Comment: Well, what ist your problem? What does not work? What are the error messages? Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) carefully

Comment: Bowdzone thanks, i have problem with edit post and part of it was eated.

Comment: You posted a wall of code, and forgot the most important part: the exact and complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Ok, i added trace of exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check extra mybatis part of "pl.xxx.mybatis.mappers" package name. I guess its "pl.xxx.mappers" only

```
<beans:bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="basePackage" value="pl.xxx.mybatis.mappers" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Only have one more issue - autowired field is not Inject to Controller

Comment: You miss  @Autowired in you controller for private UserMapper UserDao;

Comment: Sergey can you see one more stack trace?

Comment: Try to change parameterType to java.lang.Integer <select id="getUserById" parameterType="java.lang.Integer" resultType="pl.xxx.users.User">

Comment: This same. I keep mappers in /resource/mappers/*.xml - this is right syntax? classpath*:/resources/mappers/*.xml

Comment: Try classpath:resources/mappers/*.xml or classpath:mappers/*.xml (no sure what is your folder structure)

Comment: My src is probably good - when i try change i get wrong path exception. Problem must be in different place.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this:

```
<configuration>
    <...>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="UserMapper.xml" />
    <mappers>
</configuration>
```

UserMapper.xml :

```
<!-- Using ResultMap -->
<resultMap id="result" type="pl.xxx.users.User">
    <id property="id" column="id"/>
    <result property="username" column="username" />
    <result property="password" column="password" />
    <result property="isactive" column="active" />
</resultMap>
```

Check User.id type (java.lang.Integer ? Long):

```
<select id="getUserById" parameterType="java.lang.Long" resultType="result">
    SELECT  id,
            username,
            password,
            isActive
    FROM USERS
    WHERE id = #{userId}
</select>
```

Instead XML u can do this:

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;

public interface UserMapper {
@Select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = #{userid}")
Employee getUserById(Long id);

@Select("SELECT * FROM users)
List<User> getAllUsers();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, i was using in sql query in dao

```
GROUP_CONCAT(xyz SEPARATOR '<br/>')
```

The issue was with
   < br/ >
, it was expecting 
\&\l\t\; br/ \&\g\t\;

Posting this with the hope that this might help someone with similar problem.
No negative rating please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply facing feature(not a bug) :-) where the Java class name must be EXACTLY same as mapper XML file.

Your user mapper XML is camel Case against pascal case Java class name.

[Some more details](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/347)